# how can i plot news stories to show how many stories include each country on a map of the world

Tags: qgis, density

We have a table that shows the number of news stories that include particular countries over a set period of time

there are three news channels that we have this data for and we would like to show/ plot on a map of the world so that it will easily show the concentration of the stories per country whereby the marker/ number etc for each country shows clearly the concentration of stories.

Such that a country with 100 stories per period is shown as a higher concentration than one with just 10 stories per period.

We have our own data as a spread sheet

Is this possible using QGIS?

Comment: well you need to have georef data, at least your spread cheet needs to have the country identification. you wil need to join this spreadsheet to a world country shape file by country id. you should eb able to do this in QGIS

Comment: Many thanks for that - yes we do have the data set out as country specific so sounds like we can do what we want - thnaks again